# Unable to establish an HTTP or HTTPS remoting session

Tags: powershell, networking, winrm, pywin, remote-management

I am enabling windows node for ansible. For this I am enabling http and https remote session in windows 7 using below command.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://github.com/ansible/ansible/raw/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1'))"
```

I am getting the below error in office.

Could you please help me on this?

At home in another laptop it is working fine.

```
+     Throw "Unable to establish an HTTP or HTTPS remoting session."
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to estab...moting session.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to establish an HTTP or HTTPS remoting session.
```

I tried with below options:

```
set http_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set https_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

set http_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set https_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

set HTTP_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

set HTTP_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
```

i tried with all above details ...stil not working

**Update:**

Seems, connection created(Logged in). I observed below event log in windows machine

```
The WinRM service has received an unsecure HTTP connection from hostname. 

 This is not a secure configuration. 

 User Action 
 Set AllowUnencrypted to False in WinRM configuration to ensure packets are encrypted on the wire.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could be behind a proxy. If so try setting your proxy first:

```
set http_proxy=IP:Port
set https_proxy=IP:Port
```

Or you can goto your `Control Panel->Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings->Proxy servers`.

All together:

```
set http_proxy=IP:Port
set https_proxy=IP:Port

@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://github.com/ansible/ansible/raw/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1'))"
```

Comment: set http_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set https_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

set http_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set https_proxy=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

set HTTP_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N@llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

set HTTP_PROXY=http://lsl5kor:N%40llapat12@jk-proxy-apac.india.com:8080/

i tried with all above details ...still not working

Comment: U can try proxifier,

https://www.proxifier.com/download.htm.

set it up to point to you proxy. And it will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: seems no issue with proxy..test passed in proxifier

Comment: but did you see your calls go through it?

Comment: Yes ..i am able to see powershell connections

Comment: Cool then, did it send and recieve data? what error are you getting?

Comment: not getting any error. it sending and receiving data